# Ansible Java 17 priority task has no permission

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x, ansible-facts, ansible-template

I am trying to create a task in Ansible which makes my GraalVM Java JDK as the default installation. I do the following:

```
    - name: Make GraalVM Java as the selected version
      community.general.alternatives:
          name: java
          path: '{{ graalvm_home }}/bin/java'
```

Unfortunately I get the following permission error. In the community.general.alternatives I did not see any option on running the command as sudo (the device I am doing my operations is running on Linux 18). How can I remove this permission error ?

```
     Make GraalVM Java as the selected version] ***
    fatal: [default]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "cmd": "/usr/bin/update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/java java /opt/graalvm/graalvm-22.1.0-java17/bin/java 50", "msg": "update-alternatives: 
error: unable to create file '/var/lib/dpkg/alternatives/java.dpkg-tmp': Permission denied", "rc": 2, "stderr": "update-alternatives: 
error: unable to create file '/var/lib/dpkg/alternatives/java.dpkg-tmp': Permission denied\n", "stderr_lines": ["update-alternatives: 
error: unable to create file '/var/lib/dpkg/alternatives/java.dpkg-tmp': Permission denied"], "stdout": "", "stdout_lines": []}
```

Answer (score 0):

Apparently the "sudo" of Ansible is "become : true". So the following should work:

```
  - name: Make GraalVM Java as the selected version
    become: yes
    community.general.alternatives:
      name: java
      path: '{{ graalvm_home }}/bin/java'
```